# Spring-boot:bean could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am new to spring boot and i am writing CRUD operation for basic practices, here is my code.

**DemoApplication.java:**

```
 package com.example.controller;
 import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
 import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

 @SpringBootApplication
  public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

**User.java**

```
   package com.example.model;

  public class User {
   String userName;
  String password;

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

**UserServices.java:**

```
 package com.example.services;
 import com.example.model.User;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

 @Repository
 public interface UserServices {
     public String loginService(User user);
 }
```

**UserServiceImplementatioin.java:**

```
package com.example.serviceimplementation;
import com.example.model.User;
import com.example.services.UserServices;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
@Service
public class UserServiceImplementation implements UserServices {
    public String loginService(User user) {
     if(user.getUserName().equals("demouser") && user.getPassword().equals("demopass")) {
        return "Login successfully";
     }
    return "Invalid Username and password";

    }
 }
```

**ServiceController.java:**

```
  package com.example.controller;
  import com.example.services.UserServices;
  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
  import com.example.model.User;

 @RestController
 @RequestMapping(value="/askmeanything")
  public class ServiceController {
  @Autowired
  private UserServices userServices;

  public UserServices getUserServices() {
    return userServices;
  }

  public void setUserServices(UserServices userServices) {
    this.userServices = userServices;
  }

 @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String getMsg(@RequestBody User user) throws  Exception {
    return userServices.loginService(user);
  }
}
```

above code giving me the error
**Field userServices in com.example.controller.ServiceController required a bean of type 'com.example.services.UserServices' that could not be found.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `DemoApplication` is defined in he following package `com.example.controller`. Thus by default Spring will only scan that package and desendence of it. E.g. `com.example.controller.something`. It will not scan in parent packages.

Either you move your `DemoApplication` to the parent package or you have to specify the correct packages for component-scan.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example"})
```

I suggest to move the class to the parent package and let spring boot do the magic.